# Targeting the only <li> with :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)

Tags: html, css

Within a HTML container i sometime have several `<li>` items - each pr. default with a `right-margin: 25px;`

However in some cases I only have one `<li>` item, like seen so:

```
<ul class="clear-container">
    <li class="clear">
      <a href="#"><span>› </span>
        when single < li > then margin-right 0
      </a>
    </li>
    <div class="some-other-div"></div>
</ul>
```

**How do I target the `<li>` when it's the only `<li>` child?**

I've tried with the following but no luck:

```
.clear-container li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyNGwJ

Comment: your li isn't the only child, the div is also a child ...

Comment: `div` is not allowed as child of `ul`.

Comment: unor- we're not talking semantics here - but thanks for the note though :)

Comment: vals - ok, thought it was apparent that I meant the only <li> child. But ill edit the topic so that's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `.clear-container li:nth-child(1):last-of-type`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
li:only-child
```

Or

> This is your best bet:
>
> `li:only-of-type`

Or if you need specificity then try:

```
li:first-child:last-child
```

Or

```
li:first-of-type:last-of-type
```

Or

```
li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)
```

Or

```
li:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1)
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) for details on `only-child` and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) for `only-of-type`. As vals and Sidriel have already commented, there is a div within your ul, making the li **not** an `only-child` but a child with a sibling. `of-type` selector combinations or simply `only-of-type` should work in this specific situation of yours.

Comment: Selectors dependent on Child count won't work for his case as `<div class="some-other-div"></div>` is also wrapped in the parent unordered list.

Comment: I added `of-type` as well, I just noticed the div in there, thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: I haven't tried the variations you mention, since I already found the accepted solution, but great as a reference - will surely check some of them out. Thanks for contributing!